# Change size of axes title and labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a really simple question, which I am struggling to find the answer to.  I hoped someone here might be able to help me.

An example dataframe is presented below:

```
a <- c(1:10)
b <- c(10:1)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
library(ggplot2)
g = ggplot(data=df) + geom_point(aes(x=a, y=b)) +
  xlab("x axis")
g
```

I just want to learn how I change the text size of the axes titles and the axes labels.

Answer (score 462, accepted):

You can change axis text and label size with arguments `axis.text=` and `axis.title=` in function `theme()`. If you need, for example, change only x axis title size, then use `axis.title.x=`.

```
g+theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"))
```

There is good examples about setting of different `theme()` parameters in [ggplot2 page](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html).

Comment: There is also a very intuitive function [`rel()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/2.1.0/topics/rel) now. e.g. `size = rel(2.0)`

Comment: how would one change the `labs(x = "x axis")` text size *without* changing the value of the x axis ticks?

Answer (score 82):

I think a better way to do this is to change the `base_size` argument. It will increase the text sizes consistently.

```
g + theme_grey(base_size = 22)
```

As seen [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html).

Comment: If you already have other `theme` instances, this can cause conflicts.

Comment: @AdamErickson Yes so you just add `base_size = 22` to your theme of choice..

Comment: base_size does not work. 

Error in `mapply()`:
! The `base_size` theme element is not defined in the element hierarchy.

Answer (score 45):

If you are creating many graphs, you could be tired of typing for each graph the lines of code controlling for the size of the titles and texts. What I typically do is creating an object (of class "theme" "gg") that defines the desired theme characteristics. You can do that at the beginning of your code.

```
My_Theme = theme(
  axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16),
  axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
  axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16))
```

Next, all you will have to do is adding My_Theme to your graphs.

```
g + My_Theme
```

if you have another graph, g1, just write:

```
g1 + My_Theme
```

and so on.

Comment: This is the best answer, imo. There won't be many (if any) conflicts with pre-set themes.

Answer (score 14):

To change the size of (almost) all text elements, in one place, and synchronously, `rel()` is quite efficient:
   `g+theme(text = element_text(size=rel(3.5))`

You might want to tweak the number a bit, to get the optimum result. It sets both the horizontal and vertical axis labels and titles, and other text elements, on the same scale. One exception is faceted grids' titles which must be manually set to the same value, for example if both x and y facets are used in a graph:
`theme(text = element_text(size=rel(3.5)),
          strip.text.x = element_text(size=rel(3.5)),
          strip.text.y = element_text(size=rel(3.5)))`

Comment: This is a much more convenient way to modify all text sizes at once, rather than element by element.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the axis fonts and sizes using these commands, assuming that p is  your command line:

`````
  axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14),  # Change x-axis title size
  axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14),  # Change y-axis title size
  axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),   # Change x-axis label size
  axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)    # Change y-axis label size
) ````
`````

Answer (score 0):

To adjust the axis titles individually use:

```
theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20))
```

To adjust the axis labels individually use:

```
theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 20))
```